# Angular 10 ag-grid cannot set property 'setRowData' because gridOptions.api undefined

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular10

I am using following versions.

Angular CLI: 10.0.1

Node: 12.18.2

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.2

@ag-grid-community/angular@23.2.1

@ag-grid-community/all-modules@23.2.1

I am using the following way:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { SummaryDataService } from '../services/data/summary-data.service';
import {AgGridService} from  '../services/common/ag-grid.service';
import {  UtilService } from '../services/common/util.service';
import { GridOptions } from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules'; 
import { FilterComponent } from '../common/filter/filter.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: any =  null;
  noResults: boolean;
  summaryData: Array<any>;
  columnDefs: any;
  defaultColWidth: number = 200;
  numberColWidth: number = 120;
  defaultColDef: any;
  innerHeight: any;
  gridOptions: GridOptions;
  test: any;
  currentDateTo: string;
  currentDateFrom: string;
  pendingRequest: any;
  
  constructor(
    private summaryService: SummaryDataService,
    private agGridServ: AgGridService,
    private util: UtilService,
  ) {
    this.innerHeight = 450; 
    this.errorMessage = null;
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.noResults = false;
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions> {
      columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
       onGridReady: () => {
         this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
       },
      rowHeight: 48,
      headerHeight: 48,
      pivotMode: true,
      enableSorting: true,
      enableColResize: true,
      enableFilter: true,
      showToolPanel: true,
      enableRangeSelection: true,
      sortingOrder: ['asc', 'desc'],
      suppressAggFuncInHeader: true,
      suppressCopyRowsToClipboard: true,
      filter: 'text'
    }    
  }
  
  private createColumnDefs() {
    return [
      { 
        headerName: "Name", 
        field: "name", 
        width: this.defaultColWidth, 
        sortable: true, 
        resizable: true, 
        filter: true
      },
      {
        // Other columns definition
      }
    ];
  }
  
  handleUserSelection(selection) {
    this.getSummaryData();
  }
  
  getSummaryData(selections: any): void {
    this.summaryData = []
    this.errorMessage = null;
    this.noResults = false;
    this.summaryService.loadSummaryData()
      .subscribe (
      data => {
        this.summaryData = data;
        this.noResults = this.summaryData.length === 0;
        if(!this.gridOptions.api){
          return;
        }
        this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.summaryData);
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

When I see the Network tab on chrome deveoper tools, the result is returned fine from the service.

The issue is at:

```
if(!this.gridOptions.api){
          return;
}
```

Basically, in ngOnInit(), I am initializing the gridOptions (GridOptions); but my data is to be fetched later (based on some checks and user input).

*So when I am trying to use setRowData, it fails as this.gridOptions.api is undefined.*

How can I solve this?

Comment: In the gridOptions initialization, where is the api property on the object?

Comment: Where did you call handleUserSelection?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I missed it in my html code. In <ag-grid-angular> I added and undefined error is gone.
However, after that the results are not rendered on UI (no error apparent). I am looking into this further.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the api after grid initialisation.

You have to use the method onGridReady(params). You can get gridApi from the params like params.api

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it as following. When the grid finished creating, it raises an event that it is ready. The event executes a function assigned to that event as seeing in the following code. According to [Grid Event](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/) documentation page, the AgGridEvent has two properties, api, and columnApi. So you can take this property through the raised event's parameter, like params.api. You can assign this to whatever you want. Api property is needed to create, update, retrieve rows from the grid.

```
─ AgGridEvent
        │     api: GridAPI, // see Grid API
        │     columnApi: ColumnAPI // see Column API
```

**Codes**

```
<!-- IN HTML PAGE -->
<ag-grid-angular
    (gridReady)='onGridReady($event)'>
</ag-grid-angular>

 // in TYPE SCRIPT File
  onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually if you still has the issue, you should paste the code where you call `handleUserSelection` method.

BTW, you code has an explicit issue, which may cause **this.gridOptions** `undefined`:

```
this.summaryService.loadSummaryData()
  .subscribe (...)
```

You forgot to unsubscribe the observer, which may cause the issue and memory leak.